# Функция/ Unix-эра

Tags: kotlin

Реализуйте функцию getYearEra, которая для введенного в качестве аргумента функции года возвращает один из возможных вариантов его положения относительно даты начала Unix-эры (1970 год) в виде строки:

- до
- соответствует
- после (XX век)
- после (XXI век)
- далёкое будущее

Для следующих дат выведите в консоль строки вида "дата - значение функции": 1915, 1985, 1970, 2097, 3000.

Получилось следующее, но, как оказалось, это неправильно. Требуется, чтобы осуществлялся ввод дат, а затем происходило соответствие даты со значением. Каким образом это реализовать?

```
fun main() {
    val x = arrayOf(1915,1985,1970,2097,3000)
    getYearEra(x)
}

fun getYearEra(x : Array<Int>) {
        println("${x[0]} - до")
        println("${x[1]} - после (XX век)")
        println("${x[2]} - соответствует")
        println("${x[3]} - после (XXI век)")
        println("${x[4]} - далекое будущее")
}
```

Comment: Время в Unix, это **количество секунд** от 1 января 1970 года (положительные числа -- после, отрицательные -- до)